# How can I pass data to the success callback of an ExtJS-based AJAX file upload?

Tags: file-upload, extjs, forms

So, I've read a *lot* about using ExtJS's `fileuploadfield` to submit a form via an IFRAME.  I understand that I'm supposed to reply with a JSON object indicating success or failure; fine.  What I want to know is, how can I get more information back to the calling code?  I don't want to simple send a file and say "yup, that worked fine" -- I want to submit a document, act on it, and return a result.

Say I have the user upload an XML document -- I might want to do a lookup or conversion based on it and update the contents of a form on my page accordingly.  Is this even possible?  I'd strongly prefer to avoid involving Flash or embedded applets if at all possible.  If need be, I could even restrict this behavior to HTML5-compliant browsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly thought I wasn't seeing the response I sent, but it was a server-side error.  My success callback is now firing, *with* the full text of my server's response available as `f.responseText` (where `f` is the first argument to the success callback).  My mistake!